# tkinter key binding Error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a few keyboard shortcuts for a tkinter drop down menu, so for instance,'Ctrl + O' opens a file browser to open a new file. I can get single keys to bind succesfully, `self.master.bind('<Control_L>', func)`  or `self.master.bind('<O>', func)` but when I try to put them together I get:

File "C:\Users\kelly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1099, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
  File "C:\Users\kelly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1054, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: extra characters after detail in binding

This code produces my error:

```
from tkinter import *


class Application():

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        '''Create a 'master' frame of 1 row x 1 column'''
        self.master = master
        button = Button(self.master, text = 'Button', command = self.test)
        button.pack()
        #This Binding works
        self.master.bind('<Return>', self.test)
        #this Binding produces Error
        self.master.bind('<Control_L-o>', self.test)


    def test(self, event = None):
        print("Succesful Event")

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a syntax error. Change the line that binds CTRL+O to `self.master.bind('<Control_L><o>', self.test)`

Your code with that single line changed:

```
class Application():

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        '''Create a 'master' frame of 1 row x 1 column'''
        self.master = master
        button = Button(self.master, text = 'Button', command = self.test)
        button.pack()
        #This Binding works
        self.master.bind('<Return>', self.test)
        #this Binding produces Error
        self.master.bind('<Control_L><o>', self.test)


    def test(self, event = None):
        print("Succesful Event")

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
```

Comment: Thank You, Only examples I could find had it the way I had it, this works perfectly.

Comment: @Kelly Ok, odd. Maybe it worked in python 2.x or the author just made a typo; I haven't checked. Anyway, you're welcome!

Comment: @Kelly: for the definitive reference to event patterns, see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm#M5